# SQL - Many to Many relations

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many

I got these 3 tables

tblDocument(DocId, DocName) tblSubPerson(DocId, PersonId) and tblPerson(PersonId, PersonName)

i'm trying to write a mssql query where i want to return all the documents ind tblDocument which  person with eksample PersonID = 1 has an relation to

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  d.*
FROM    tblDocument d INNER JOIN
        tblSubPerson p  ON  d.DocId = p.DocId
WHERE   p.PersonId = 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1144f/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblDocument
WHERE DocId IN (
    SELECT DocId
    FROM tblSubPerson
    WHERE PersonId = 1
    GROUP BY DocId
)
```